# How can i make a image grid with different heights and fixed width like Offer up app?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

How to make a offer up kind of grid UI (please look the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S77TT.jpg)), it has three same sized columns and height differs according to image size. i have implemented the view with the 3 linear layouts and a scroll view. but it's not very supportive when it comes to memory management. Can i make the view with grid view (since height is different)? or should i use any other method? or is it ok to use scrollview to load about 100 images at a time?

Comment: you can use recyclerview with GridLayoutManager

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I'm not very familiar with recyclerview. anyway thanks for quick response

Comment: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/grid-recyclerview-with-images-and-text.html IS this the way you suggesting? (Instead of Linear layout use Grid Layout)

Comment: Try StaggeredGridLayoutManager of RecyclerView
[https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks Kunu, i tried the StaggeredGridLayoutManager it was pretty cool and it worked. if this is an answer i will mark this as accepted since this is comment i cant do that